# Execute SqueezeBox OnClose Event Multiple Time

Tags: component, jquery, javascript

I have a problem executing onclose event multiple time on page.
I have used handler:iframe to display view in squeezebox modal.

I have written following javascript:-

**on child page**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#add_agent").on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery('#agentsList input:checked').each(function() {
                window.parent.agents.push(jQuery(this).val());
            });
            window.parent.SqueezeBox.close();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**on parent page**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.agents = [];
    window.SqueezeBox.addEvent('onClose',function() {
        if(window.agents.length !== 0){
            jQuery("#agentChecked").css('display','block');
</script>
```

onClose event on parent page works fine for the first time. But at second time of closing modal, this event doesn't response.

What should I Do???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.SqueezeBox.initialize({
        onClose:function(){
        }
});
```

This Solved Problem